# Are there a design pattern to controlling slave jobs or management of slaves from master?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

Management or Controller design patern. I have one class doing two different job in structure. Are there a design pattern to refactor it in more maintable way? Or, how should I divide this class in more maintable way?

```
                     Management Class does

Task launching                            recovery management
- create Callable Task                   - if thread failed to start, re-assign 
- submit tasks to ExecutorService              the same task to other thread 
- start ExecutorService                  - if task is not halted unexpectedly,
- get result of each task                      re-assign the task to new thread
                                         - if thread halted, get already done 
                                               job and restart the thread for
                                               not done jobs
                                         - other task and thread related recovery
                                               scenarios

Settings
- set requirements of management class in system level
- determine optimal number of threads should be run
- determine optimal number of task to be created
- create and manage system configuration file - store system settings, get system
  settings-
```

Before down-voting or trying to close, if you are constructive, write comment so that I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply SRP: [Single Responsibility principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html).

Indeed, in your case, your actual class does too much: it has three responsibilities:

1. Configuring the pool of threads
2. Launching the tasks
3. Recover failed tasks

I would split your whole class into three classes:

1. Settings (settings)
2. TaskExecutor  (launcher)
3. FailedTaskRecoverer  (recoverer)

Note that it's not a design pattern, but part of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.

Comment: how can I know thread status in other class? If I inject dependency to other classes, I will create coupling, wilnot I?

Comment: You may want to implement a wait/notify mechanism to inform of thread status, or just have a reference of the `Future` to know whether there was an exception or success.

Comment: @GeorgeWathson Not all coupling is inherently bad -- if all code was *entirely* decoupled, it couldn't communicate at all! Mik378's suggestion of using the `Future` is a good one.